# How to dynamically add stroke to drawables?

Tags: android, android-drawable

I use function drawCircle() to return a ShapeDrawable object which is an oval and use ImageView.setImageDrawable() to set it.  But how can I add a 2dp-border to the oval drawable? I tried using GrandientDrawable but no matter how big the value of border thickness is, the border is barely seen on the emulator.

Here's my function drawCircle():

```
public ShapeDrawable drawCircle (int diameter) {
        OvalShape ovalShape = new OvalShape();
        ShapeDrawable drawable = new ShapeDrawable(ovalShape);
        drawable.getPaint().setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.textColorHint));
        drawable.getPaint().setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        drawable.setIntrinsicHeight(diameter);
        drawable.setIntrinsicWidth(diameter);

        return drawable;
    }
```

Here's my function setStroke():

```
public void setStroke(ImageView view) {
        GradientDrawable gradientDrawable = new GradientDrawable();
        gradientDrawable.setShape(GradientDrawable.OVAL);
        gradientDrawable.setStroke(100, Color.WHITE);
        view.setBackground(gradientDrawable);
    }
```

Here's how I use it:

```
// Calculate diameter
int selector_one_diameter = (int)(selector_diameter * 1/6);
// Get ImageView
ImageView one_img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.circle_one_selector_img);
// Set drawable
one_img.setImageDrawable(drawCircle(selector_one_diameter));
// Set stroke
setStroke(one_img);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to work with circular  `imageview` is working with [this](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView) library , too easy to work with and it gives you all customizations you are looking for

Comment: So use it and don't forget it :)

Answer (score 0):

How about creating an oval.xml file under drawable folder and using dashWidth and width instead of gradientDrawable?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
<stroke
    android:dashWidth="2dp"
    android:width ="3dp"
    android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: you can fit in whatever value you want for the dashwidth and width.I hope this was of help

Comment: Thanks for help! But if I don't set padding to ImageView, the drawable background won't be visible because the ImageDrawable that I gave to the ImageView covered it up. So, by setting padding to ImageView, this did worked out!